# How to deploy / define a ECS (Fargate) Instance using Terraform and CodeBuild

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a service running on ECS Fargate, which gets deployed by CodePipeline / CodeBuild.

Terraform:

- Defines ECS Fargate Task
- Defines CodePipeline
- Defines CodeBuild Step

CodePipeline:

- Fetches changes from GitHub
- Runs CodeBuild
- Deploy to ECS using CodeBuild Artifacts

CodeBuild:

- Builds a new Docker image
- Pushes it to an ECR repo
- Returns an `imagedefinitions.json` as an artifact

The issue with this is that after a commit to GitHub, CodePipeline deploys a new version (which also creates a new revision of the task definition), which in turn causes the Terraform state to be out of sync (the task definition is a required parameter of `aws_ecs_service`).

I see two possible solutions:

- Introduce a shared Terraform state and make CodeBuild / CodePipeline write to it. (seems overly complicated for a simple setup)
- Use `ignore_changes`  to ignore any changes to the task definition (I guess that means when updating the task definition that needs to be commented out, which will be forgotten at some point).

Are there any better solutions? If not, which would be the preferred way to do this?

Comment: A discussion about how to deal with task definitions is also available here: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/258